# Problems to emulate after Xcode update

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

After update my Xcode from 10.1 to 10.2, I have problem to emulate the app on ios emulators.

After I run `$ ionic cordova emulate ios -l`, I get this:

```
BUILD SUCCEEDED
[cordova]  
[cordova]  No target specified for emulator. Deploying to undefined simulator
[cordova]  Device type "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.undefined" could not be found.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

```
$ ionic cordova emulate ios --list
Available ios virtual devices:
```

So I've did
`$ cd platforms/ios/cordova/ && npm i ios-sim@latest`

But, I keep getting  `No target specified for emulator. Deploying to undefined simulator`, just like before.

I also tried instal the next version of ios-sim, but I think it's compatible.

```
$ ionic info

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 (/Users/jeansilva/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (13 plugins total)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/jeansilva/Library/Android/sdk/)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   ios-sim           : ios-sim/9.0.0-dev.1 darwin-x64 node-v8.12.0
   NodeJS            : v8.12.0 (/Users/jeansilva/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.2 Build version 10E125
```

Comment: It is a known issue with ios-sim. [You can follow the issue here](https://github.com/ios-control/ios-sim/issues/253)

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar problem, after hours of making app run on simulator following command works for me

```
ionic cordova emulate ios --livereload --consolelogs --target="iPhone-6,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-10-1"
```

or you can try this if above don't work

```
ionic cordova emulate ios --livereload --consolelogs --target="iPhone-6,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-10-1" --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

Let me know if it doesn't solve your issue.